# check the last element of the object array in the list

Tags: groovy

I have the list `eventsLogs` of type `List<Object[]>` below  how can I check the last element of the object(last element in the array)  in the list?

```
def eventLogs = queryHelper.query(query, 
["organization":organization, 
"fromDate":startDate, 
"toDate":endDate], 0);
```

Comment: What is `queryHelper.query`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: it is is a method that return a list of object array with String elments `List<Object[]>`. Also the element of the object array is of type String.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `last()`, to get the last `Object[]`, and then `last()` again, to get the last element in the array:

```
queryHelper = [ query : { query, map, priority ->
    [
        ['floyd'],
        ['stones'],
        ['led'],
        ['beatles'],
        ['bowie']
    ].collect { it as Object[] }
}]

def eventLogs = queryHelper.query(
    'query', 
    ["organization":'organization', 
    "fromDate":'startDate', 
    "toDate":'endDate'], 
    0);

assert eventLogs.last().last() == 'bowie'
```